# Is there any tools available for converting JSON data to Avro on the fly?

Tags: avro

I need a utility to convert my incoming JSON data(on which I have no control) to Avro Format(on the fly)ie. without using any Hive query, MR job etc.
I am able to generate the avrso schema perfectly.
I am aware that we do have an Avro Tool for the purpose.

- From JSON to Avro: DataFileWriteTool
- From Avro to JSON: DataFileReadTool

But the challenge is that it accepts JSON data in a typesafe format types.I am facing the exact same issue when I try to use this tool.

[How to fix Expected start-union. Got VALUE_NUMBER_INT when converting JSON to Avro on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485580/how-to-fix-expected-start-union-got-value-number-int-when-converting-json-to-av)

Any pointers/help ?