# Allowing multiple types in an Avro schema field?

Tags: javascript, json, avro

I am fairly new to Avro schemas, and I am aware that a union can be used to allow multiple types e.g:

```
"message": ["null", "string"]
```

However, I am having an issue when the passed json value is a string. e.g:

```
"message": "Hello World!"
```

The error I am getting is:

```
failed to convert json to avro expected start-union. got value_string
```

I have seen the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27499930/5481419, where it is stated that you must encode the JSON like so:

```
"message": {"string": "Hello World!"}
```

However, this is not possible for me, as the JSON that is getting mapped by the Avro schema is a response from an external endpoint, and it just returns a string as the value (It can also return null, hence why I need the union). Is there any other way around this? I am also required to use Avro schemas here.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @nlloyd sorry, I have added in the error I am getting: failed to convert json to avro expected start-union. got value_string