# JSON to Avro conversion exception - Expected start-union. Got VALUE_STRING

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, schema, avro

**I have the following avsc (Avro schema) :**

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "DataEventId",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "redeliveredDataEventIndices",
      "type": { "type": "array", "items": "int" },
      "doc" : "Data event indices",
      "default": []
    },
  ],
  "namespace": "com.xxx.xxx.xxx"
}
```

When i try to convert json to avro with this Schema i get the following error :

```
org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected start-union. Got VALUE_STRING
```

My input data :

```
{"redeliveredDataEventIndices":"[]"}
```

I know this is a duplicate of [How to fix Expected start-union. Got VALUE_NUMBER_INT when converting JSON to Avro on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485580/how-to-fix-expected-start-union-got-value-number-int-when-converting-json-to-av) but how to give input for the type array (redeliveredDataEventIndices is array of type int in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input data has the array wrapped in quotes, thus treating it as a string.

Try this instead:

```
{"redeliveredDataEventIndices":[]}
```